# Messaging HA policy on jboss 7 domain mode

Tags: jboss7.x

I'm trying to implement HA policy for messaging on domain, but I have a problem with the slave-host.

This is the log:

```
"WFLYCTL0030: No resource definition is registered for address [
    (\"subsystem\" => \"messaging-activemq\"),
    (\"server\" => \"clustermqfse\"),
    (\"jms-topic\" => \"test2\")
]"
```

The host-master, on the other hand, is ok. I saw the host.xml of both and are egual.

How could I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined a topic with the name=test2 under the activemq subsystem config of the ha profile in domain.xml?